# Modify the "Comment as" options in Blogger Dynamic Views template

Tags: comments, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

My website is https://testfnm11.blogspot.com based on Blogger Dynamic Views Mosaic template.

In the Comments widget, I would like to remove the option to comment from "Google Account".

The reason is that these days most browsers, by default, block third-party cookies, or have cross-site-tracking disabled. This disables the the ability to post comments from "Google Account" and my viewers get frustrated trying to post comments.

However the Name/URL and Anonymous options do work even with third-party cookies or cross-site-tracking disabled.

Hence I would like to only have the Name/URL and Anonymous options available.

Also, in the "Name/Url" option, I would like to rename it to only "Name", and remove the URL field. Or if the URL field cannot be removed then I would like to put "optional" text in the URL field so that viewers understand that it is not required to put both name and url.

Additional information:

1. In my Blogger Settings, I have set Comment Moderation to "Always" (otherwise posting comments even from Name/Url and Anonymous does not work).
2. Comment Location is set to "Full Page".
3. Reader Access is set to "Public".

Comment: Hi firoze, Unfortunately, Blogger doesn't allow modifying comments form any way.

Comment: Hi Bassam, that is unfortunate. But thank you anyway.